# How to create a custom numeric spacing for the x-axis, e.g. like 1/x?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to check points on a plot and matplotlib is sorting x-axis automatically. I know it normally makes sense with integers, time, etc. In my case I would like to plot the x-axis "as is", that is, without the x-axis being sorted in increasing order. The closest I have been able to get is to use integers and `set_xticklabels` only. But this solution doesn't allow to see the correct x-coordinate in the status bar (x shows blank).

Here are 3 alternatives I tried:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 100
y1, y2 = np.linspace(N,0,N)+np.random.normal(size=N), np.random.normal(size=N)
x0 = np.arange(0,0.5,0.5/N)
x = 1/x0
idx = ~np.isinf(x)

# 1. Using x directly
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.plot(x[idx], y1[idx], c='r', linestyle='-', marker='+')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(x[idx], y2[idx], c='b', linestyle='--', marker='x')
    
# 2. Using integers instead and the setting xticks
xa = np.arange(len(x)) 
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.plot(xa[idx], y1[idx], c='r', linestyle='-', marker='+')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(xa[idx], y2[idx], c='b', linestyle='--', marker='x')
ax1.set(xticks=x[idx], xlim=(x[np.isfinite(x)].min(), x[np.isfinite(x)].max()))

# 3. Using integers instead, ignoring xticks and setting xtickslabels. Here the problem is that I can find the x reference when clicking points in the plot
xa = np.arange(len(x)) 
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.plot(xa[idx], y1[idx], c='r', linestyle='-', marker='+')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(xa[idx], y2[idx], c='b', linestyle='--', marker='x')
ax1.set_xticklabels(["{:.2f}".format(u) for u in x[idx]], rotation=45)
```

Comment: What do you mean with `plot the x-axis "as is".`? If you provide `(x, y)` coordinates for the points they will be placed where you specify. What happens if you only plot with `plot(y1)`? That should plot the data as it appears inside `y1`.

Comment: You can convert the x's to strings, e.g. `xa_idx = [f'{xi:.4g}' for xi in x[idx]]` and then use `ax1.plot(xa_idx, y1[idx], ...)`

Comment: @Pietro I have clarified what I mean. If I plot y only is like having integers in the x-axis (my second option)

Comment: @JohanC this would be my 3rd option, the problem is that it is not possible to see the value of x at a given point in the plot.

Comment: @JohanC thanks for the suggestion, I have done a quick check. It seems that  xvalue on the plot seems to be related to the 1st xaxis only so I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to a [`secondary_axis()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html), [`ax.set_xscale()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xscale.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xscale) also [accepts a function](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/scales/scales.html) and its inverse as parameter. This will also display the correct `x` in the status bar.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator
import numpy as np

def invert_values(x):
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
        return 1 / x

N = 100
y1, y2 = np.linspace(N, 0, N) + np.random.normal(size=N), np.random.normal(size=N)
x0 = np.arange(0, 0.5, 0.5 / N)
with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
    x = 1 / x0
idx = ~np.isinf(x)

plt.style.use('ggplot')
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(x[idx], y1[idx], c='r', linestyle='-', marker='+')
ax1.set_xscale('function', functions=(invert_values, invert_values))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(x[idx][::10]))
ax1.set_xlim(x[idx][np.array([-1, 0])])
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(x[idx], y2[idx], c='b', linestyle='--', marker='x')

plt.show()
```

[image: function as xscale]

Comment: I see that you can display the x value. However I'm not sure if this solution avoids the x-axis to be sorted. Please note that the first valid value of the `x`array  is 200, 100, ...., also y1 is a decreasing function but after calling plot(x,y) both y and x are sorted. Maybe it is not possible to achieve what I want. I would like matplotlib to keep the given ordering of the arrays and it seems that's only possible by using strings in the xlabels, but then the x values are not displayed.

Comment: If you want the x-axis in decreasing order, just exchange the x limits: `ax1.set_xlim(x[idx][np.array([-1, 0])])`